# Согласно чему - сочетание с Дательным?

Tags: предлоги

Но вот тут что тогда: "Однако литературная норма русского языка, согласно которой следует говорить и писать..."
Где тут Дательный? 
Согласно народу - Дательный ли, если имеется в виду, что согласование происходит по "много народу"?

Я понимаю, что от моих вопросов у знатоков смех. Но эти знатоки созреть должны до моего уровня. Большое видится на расстоянии. Ваш источник - писанина деятелей. Мой источник - понятия. Прямое и посредническое восприятие - разные вещи.

Предлог "согласно" образован от "согласование", а не от созвучие, соответствие.
Например, "согласно видео": 
1) так же, как на видео (например, повторяем упражнения); 
2) видео говорит, что человек обманывал (выдавал себя не за того). 
Как вы прикрутите это к Дательному? А к Родительному (ой, к нему-то как раз и не прикрутите)? Я прикручу, а вы - нет.

Дательный (кому? чему?) видео: 
1) либо мы даём что-то этому видео (действие идет от нас); 
2) либо самому видео что-то нужно (действие запрашивает видео).

Answer (score 3):

> Где тут Дательный?

Немного странный вопрос, но помогу. В приведенном предложении присутствует только одно слово в дательном падеже: **которой**. Склонение местоимений объясняется в учебнике по русскому языку за 6-й класс.

Но Вы правильно запомнили, что предлог **согласно** должен употребляться с дательным падежом.

Comment: Норма о чём говорит? 1. Узаконенное установление, признанный обязательным порядок, строй чего-н. 2. Установленная мера, средняя величина чего-н. ... Опять всё сложно Дательный и Родительный пересекаются. Что такое норма?

Comment: согласно народу - много народу... количество влияет, а это Родительный падеж, а не Дательный

Comment: Склонение существительных проходят раньше. Его можно повторить (или же узнать в первый раз в жизни) по учебнику 4-го класса. Старайтесь на таком уровне знаний использовать более простой язык и не задумываться пока об очень сложных (для этого уровня) вопросах.

Comment: я-то вас понимаю, а вот вы меня - 0... не суйтесь. когда увидите Нижегородца

Comment: Я Вас понимать не собираюсь — это, знаете ли, чревато. Мне здесь для общения достаточно понимания норм русского языка. Сделайте, пожалуйста, свой сайт и там распоряжайтесь.

Comment: :) у меня шесть собственных сайтов!

Comment: да ещё, к тому же, три рассказа на проза.ру... вы видели, чтобы я на них ссылки давал? мне этого не нужно

Comment: это я вам плюсик поставил

Answer (score 1):

"*Однако литературная норма русского языка, согласно (чему?) которой (норме какой?) следует говорить и писать...*" - которой - союзное слово, выраженное 
 относительным местоимением в  дательном падеже.

Вы хотите оспорить? Считаете, что это родительный падеж?

```
       Согласно народу - Дательный ли, если имеется в виду, что 
        согласование происходит по "много народу"?
```

Во-первых, не согласование, а управление, и управляет слово ***согласно*** всё же дательным падежом, а если с предлогом С, то творительным: согласно с чем?

Значение слова Согласно по словарю Ушакова:

> СОГЛАСНО 
>   1. Нареч. к **согласный** 1 в 5 знач., дружно, единодушно. Жить согласно. Петь согласно. Все граждане согласно показали. Пушкин. 
>   2. с предлогом "с". Нареч. к согласный 1 в 3 знач., соответственно, сходно, сообразно с чем-н., по чему-н. (см. "по" в 4 знач.). Поступать
>   согласно с законом (по закону). || **с дат. п. (с род. п. - неправ.),**
>   без "с". То же - в знач. предлога (чаще канц.). Сердце билось согласно
>   всей музыке тишины. Пришвин. Согласно предписанию (по предписанию).
>   **Согласно чему-н. (но не согласно чего-н.).**

http://tolkslovar.ru/s8870.html

```
  Предлог "согласно" образован от "согласование", а не 
  от созвучие, соответствие. Например, "согласно 
  видео":
```

Строго говоря, предлог **согласно** образован не от сущ. согласование, а от прилагательного **согласный** - согласный с чем? - отсюда творит. пад. с предлогом **С**: **согласно с законом**, но ему синонимично **по закону**, отсюда  дат.п. **согласно закону**.

Теперь о "много народу"(много кого? чего?) - **род. пад**. Это так, но **вовсе не означает, что окончание -у говорит об обязательном соответствии родительному падежу.**

Родительный падеж рассматривают как **собственно родительный** , или родительный определительный (производство сыра, продажа чая), и **количественно-родительный , или отделительный**  (килограмм сыру, стакан чаю).

> В реализации падежных значений участвует не только сама падежная форма
>   имени существительного. Семантика падежей определяется: а) формой и  значением **управляющего слова**: любить (уважать, почитать) мать (брата, сестру); положить сахару (изюму, меду) 
>   b) формой и значением
>   **управляемого слова**: звать сестру – звать сестрой, 
>   рисовать карандашом c) семантикой предлога: ехать через город – ехать в  город, считаться другом – считаться с другом
>
> Родительный приглагольный употребляется: для обозначения прямого  объекта,  для
>   обозначения объекта после глаголов со значением желания, достижения, ожидания, опасения, удаления: желать успеха, ждать друга, искать  успокоения.
>
> Родительный приименной употребляется: для выражения различных  определительных отношений ; для обозначения субъекта, являющегося  производителем действия или носителем определенного признака: пение
>   соловья, песни соловья; для выражения прямого
>   объекта, на который направлено действие, выраженное отглагольным  существительным: чтение книги – читать книгу (В.П.);
>   ** для обозначения количественных отношений: стакан чаю килограмм рису,
>   полк солдат, табун лошадей**
>
> Традиционный родительный падеж у некоторых существительных располагает
>   двумя формами: чая – чаю, сахару – сахара, сыра – сыру.
>
> Но не во всех контекстах можно употребить две
>   формы. Например:
>
> 1) Контекст ***У … есть недостаток***. Предмет, обладающий недостатком, допускает формы
>   **на –а/ -я**: у чая есть недостаток, у сахара есть недостаток, у сыра есть
>   недостаток.
>
> 2) Контекст ***стакан ...***. Предмет в данном количестве допускает формы **как
>   на –а/ -я, так и на –у/ -ю**: стакан чая – стакан чаю, стакан сахара –
>   стакан сахару, головка сыра – головка сыру.
>
> **Нет таких контекстов, формы в которых традиционно относятся к  родительному падежу и могут оканчиваться только на –у/-ю.**

Так что  **много народу** (количественно-родительный падеж) и **согласно народу** (дательный падеж) - совершенно разное значение и разные падежи, хотя одинаковые окончания.

Comment: Это сложный вопрос. Заброшенный, никем недоказанный, просто кто-то решил, что надо бы вот так и на этом всё. Чтобы выяснить правильность Дательного и Родительного падежей, придётся:
1) разбираться с понятиями "основание" и "основа"; 2) Отдельно заострить внимание на понятии "основание", потому что под основанием можно иметь в виду два положения; 3) в Родительном окончания меда, мёду (чая, чаю) могут путаться с Дательным (согласно народу - много народу); 4) сами падежи и их полные расклады: шесть делений в Родительном и шесть делений в Дательном;

Comment: 5) разбираться с самим "согласно", потому что его могут смешивать с понятиями: "созвучно", "соответственно" и указывать на то, что предлог сочетается только с Дательным.
Может быть поэтому этот вопрос постоянно всплывает - он же в подвисшем состоянии.

Comment: Дайте расклад по падежам. Хотя бы только Дательный. В общественности этого нету, и как быть? Опять мне давать полный расклад?

Comment: И про "согласно народу" вы не поняли. "Много народу" - количество. На основании количества делается согласование, то есть "согласно народу" (согласно его количеству) - какой падеж?

Comment: Всё. Сам разобрался. Просто оказалось. Даже неинтересно. И Дательный и Родительный почти об одном и том же говорят. Оба применимы. Розенталь со своей "на основании" меня запутал. Не обязательно разбирать "на основании". В который раз убеждаюсь, что нельзя верить справочникам.